# Grub doesn't appear after windows 10 upgrade

Tags: 14.04, boot, dual-boot, grub2, windows-10

After a Windows 10 upgrade I'm not able to choose what operating system I want to boot, (I have installed Windows 10 and Ubuntu 14.04 LTS) because Windows 10 starts automatically. I created a live USB with the latest version of boot repair disk and I ran the recommended repair option but it did not work. Here you can find the output from BootInfo:

http://paste.ubuntu.com/16953932/

Any ideas?

Comment: That's because the Win 10 install overwrote the MBR. What OS did you upgrade from?

Comment: From Win 10 itself. An automatically update that seemed more a version upgrade (many reboot and a percentage on the screen. It lasted about an hour)

Answer (score 1):

Almost the same situation as mine. I have Windows 10 along side Ubuntu 16.04 LTS. I also have dual boot system with bootloader as grub.
I faced the same issue i.e. after latest Windows 10 update - the computer will not show the grub screen and then directly boot into Windows 10. I cannot go into Linux at all.

This is what I did.
Once booted inside Windows. Press `Windows + R or right click on Start menu to get run command.`
when you are typing run.exe select as run as administrator.
Once you are in command shell kind of windows
type this command:

```
bcdedit /set {bootmgr} path \EFI\ubuntu\shimx64.efi
```

Make sure that command executed successfully. Your command could be slightly different - please refer to your initial grub install/config logs for the correct command.
It worked for me and I believe it will work for anybody else.

Note: This will work when you upgrade Windows 10 within Windows 10.

Answer (score 0):

```
sudo fdisk -l

sudo mount /dev/sda1 /mnt

sudo grub-install --root-directory=/mnt/ /dev/sda
```

Note `SDA` is not the specific partition but the entire HDD like `sda`, `sdb`

Comment: Here the output from command sudo grub-install --root-directory=/mnt/ /dev/sda/:  
Installing for i386-pc platform.  
grub-install: warning: this GPT partition label contains no BIOS Boot Partition; embedding won't be possible.
grub-install: warning: Embedding is not possible.  GRUB can only be installed in this setup by using blocklists.  However, blocklists are UNRELIABLE and their use is discouraged..
grub-install: error: will not proceed with blocklists.

Comment: Seems to be a little tricky.
Please try https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/grub2/+bug/1061255/comments/26

Comment: I don't see the string "PRIVHEAD" when i launch the first command!